# Play Stream Delphi XE4

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I use Delphi XE4 (iOS) want to play one stream live audio, using a port and ip. How to do this?

Play audio locally just assign the component filemane
  MediaPlayer1.FileName: = GetHomePath PathDelim + + 'Documents' + + PathDelim 'soundsample.mp3';

Regards
Leonardo